# how can i drag a label to a picturebox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, drag-and-drop, label, picturebox

i want to drag a label2 and drop it into pictureBox1, however it didn't work and i don't know what the problem is

```
    private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
          pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;

        if (CurrentDrag.Equals("clock1"))
        {
            Label pnlDroggedTheme = (Label)sender;
            pnlDroggedTheme.Height = pictureBox1.Height;
            pnlDroggedTheme.Width = pictureBox1.Width;


            label2.Visible = false;
            correct++;
            label1.Text = correct.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(" cerrect answer");

        }
        else
            wronge++;
            label1.Text = wronge.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("wronge answer");
    }
```

this the DragEnter method for pictureBox1

```
    private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
```

here it should copy data if the dropped element's data is from type string which is the label

```
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; 
         }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        } 
    }
```

the label dragging works just fine but i can't drop it in the picturebox

```
    private void label2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentDrag = "clock1";
        Label labelV = (Label)sender;
        labelV .DoDragDrop(labelV .BackColor, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the drag drop event check if the type of data is `System.String` and perform no action if it isn't, Yet you are doing a drag drop for `System.Color`. What I think you want to do

```
Label labelV = (Label)sender;
labelV .DoDragDrop(labelV.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

You should either do that or modify your drag drop event to accept `System.Color`.

Also, you should move your `pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;` to the constructor or `Form_Load` or just set the property to true at design time.

Comment: but the problem is that the dropping part isn't working, maybe something is wrong in the "pictureBox1_DragEnter" method

Comment: @ELF NO. The problem is that the drag drop event is not recognizing what you are droping therefore `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;` is executed. and whatever is is your drag enter is not executed.

Comment: yea sorry you are right about the type, but still the dropping isn't working.